# Round from milliseconds to minutes

Tags: r

I have time data in hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds. I also have a descriptor for what occurs at each timepoint. An example of my dataset is as follows:

```
StartTime <- c("00:00:00:00", "00:00:14:04", "00:01:51:06", "00:03:30:02")
Events <- c("Start whistle", "Pass", "Shot", "Pass")
RawData <- data.frame(StartTime, Events)
```

I now wish to create a new column that rounds according to minutes played, from the `StartTime` column. My anticipated output would be:

```
MinutesPlayed <- c(0, 0, 2, 3)
```

I have tried to round using the following code, however it includes the date (unnecessary for my work) and still keeps time in H:M:S format.

```
RawData$MinutesPlayed <- strptime(RawData$StartTime, "%H:%M:%S")
```

Where am I please going wrong?

Comment: What does the fourth set of numbers represent?  Milliseconds?

Comment: Yes, it represents milliseconds. Apologies, I should have made that clear in the post and not just the title.

Comment: `difftime` has nice units capabilities: `difftime(as.POSIXct(RawData$StartTime, tz = 'UTC', format = '%T'), Sys.Date(), units = 'mins')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're rounding up, then the last element should go up to 4 (since 30.02 seconds rounds to 1 minute). Here's an idea using `strptime()`, rounding the minutes.

```
## replace the last colon with a decimal point
st <- sub("(.*):(.*)", "\\1.\\2", StartTime)
## convert to POSIXlt and grab the rounded minutes
round(strptime(st, "%H:%M:%OS"), "mins")$min
# [1] 0 0 2 4
```

Comment: This did not work when StartTime = 01:00:18:12, for example, minutes returned = 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(RawData$StartTime),":"), function(x)
       #Use 'ceiling' or 'round' instead of 'floor' as needed
       floor(as.numeric(x[1])*60 + #hours to minutes
       as.numeric(x[2]) + #minutes
       as.numeric(x[3])/60 + #seconds to minutes
       as.numeric(x[4])/60000)) #milliseconds to minutes
#[1] 0 0 1 3
```